# Craft Commerce Currency - Email template not showing currency

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there something else you have to add to Craft Commerce Email templates to show the amounts in the order currency used? It always shows the default currency (i.e. GBP) when it was ordered in USD.

The email template has been updated to the new tag of commerceCurrency.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the currency to the conversion filter.

The order is always made in the primary currency, but the payment currency that they made the payment in might be different, so you need to pass `order.paymentCurrency` to the conversion filter.

You can read about using different currencies here: 
https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-currencies

In addition to just changing the filter to `|commerceCurrency` take a look at the docs for the filter for the optional formatting and conversion options:
https://craftcommerce.com/docs/twig-filters